# Count characters using function (frequency)

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, char

Trying to count characters and improve my code i made a few changes instead of using while loop for example. Curious if anyone got any advice how i could improve my code to make it more professional and cheaper?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int countingCharacters(char *message, int size, char charsToBeCounted);

int main()
{
    char myString[] = "Hello World!";

    int size = strlen(myString);

    char charToBeCounted = 'a';
    int i = 0;
    int counter = 0;


    while (myString[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (myString[i] == charToBeCounted)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)
    {
        printf("%c: %d\n", charToBeCounted, countingCharacters(myString, size, charToBeCounted));
        charToBeCounted++;
    }
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

int countingCharacters(char *message, int size, char charsToBeCounted)
{
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (message[i] == charsToBeCounted)
        counter++;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Why is that `while` loop even there? You are not using `counter` anywhere.

Comment: "advice how i could improve my code to make it more professional and cheaper?" --> Consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com - a better site choice.  (This assumes it functions correctly)

Comment: I see at least 4 improvements to `countingCharacters()`,  Post working code at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: To really improve your code: step 1: Clearly separate out the _code_ from the _test code_.  Are you concerned only about `countingCharacters()` or everything after `char myString[] = "Hello World!";` or what?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the whole thing twice.
first in main with the loop.

```
while (myString[i]!='\0'){...}
```

And the again with `countingCharacters`. Wasting a lot of resources.

Additionally, if you are using `strlen` don't do `while (myString[i]!='\0)`. Replace that with `for (i=0;i<size;i++)`. You are investing to find `size` and then not using it. Alternatively don't use `strlen` and just do `while (myString[i]!='\0')`

FYI: You can use `'\0'`and `0` equivalently (the integer value of `\0` is `0`).

Comment: `\0` conveys the meaning better.

Comment: True that. It's just that `0` is easier on the fingers. :P

Comment: `while (myString[i] != '\0')` is easy on the eyes of code reviews and maintainers, a higher cost than developing should you agree with [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3610582/).  `while (myString[i])` is the terse alternative.